# Android MediaPlayer setDataSource() Throwing IllegalStateException Error

Tags: android, video, media-player

While I use almost the same code to play two videos, the first works perfectly, but the second does not.  When I press the next video button, the program crashed with:

```
WARN/System.err(15726): java.lang.IllegalStateException
WARN/System.err(15726):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
```

Source code:

the first play code:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    playURI = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("playURI");
    showDebugInfo("play uri "+playURI);
    Log.e("Gplayer on create", "play uri "+playURI);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(playURI);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }
```

when press next button it runs the following code:

```
   String uri = listAdapter.getItem(position).getItem().getFirstResource().getValue();
    showDebugInfo(" Uri "+uri);
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
```

Why does this happen? and I check the two parts only the different that, the first one is new a mediaplayer and the second is let the mediaplayer stop and reset then the same.

Comment: "almost the same code". Can you show them both? Also, how you're handling the "next video" button click handler? The way you have it should work.

Comment: a lot of times these types of errors are related to file permissions of whatever media you're trying to play..

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the videos, so the crashing video plays first? Is it always the second video that has problems, or is it that specific video?

Comment: @ChadSchultz it always the second video that has problem not the specific one.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit I think it is not for that, cause there are two videos A and B , no matter which I play first , it works well , and the second doesn't

Comment: @kcoppock I have already add the two parts of code. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

You need to call `mediaPlayer.reset();` before you are calling in the second video `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);` the reason is, because the function `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri);` can be called only on idle state, and `mediaPlayer.reset();` is the function that take you to idle state.

I understand it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420837/java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-mediaplayer-setdatasource-using-ringtone-cla), even though the question is a bit different.