# java.lang.IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer.setDataSource, using Ringtone class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception, ringtone

I had a crash reported by an user (Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 4.4) and I do not understand what is happening. It seems imporbable but maybe some people have encountered the same problem, or similar.

Here is the trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1383)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1367)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1302)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1240)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:986)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:951)
at android.media.Ringtone.setUri(Ringtone.java:219)
at android.media.Ringtone.setStreamType(Ringtone.java:89)
at com.aasfet.clocklight.WakeActivity$RingAsyncTask.doInBackground(WakeActivity.java:510)
at com.aasfet.clocklight.WakeActivity$RingAsyncTask.doInBackground(WakeActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 3 more
```

Here is the part of my code that is in the error:

```
private class RingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            int previousVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            int newVolume = (int)(volume * (float)maxVolume);
            if(newVolume < 1){
                newVolume = 1;
            }
            if(progressive){
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 1, 0);
            }else{
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, newVolume, 0);
            }
            getRingtone().setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            getRingtone().play();
...
```

getRingtone() is one of my functions and returns a Ringtone object that was obtained with a RingtoneManager cursor in the activity's onResume, I do not think there is any problem there.

In the Android source, Ringtone.setStreamType calls Ringtone.setURI. Here is setURI:

```
 public void setUri(Uri uri) {
168        destroyLocalPlayer();
169
170        mUri = uri;
171        if (mUri == null) {
172            return;
173        }
174
175        // TODO: detect READ_EXTERNAL and specific content provider case, instead of relying on throwing
176
177        // try opening uri locally before delegating to remote player
178        mLocalPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
179        try {
180            mLocalPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, mUri);
181            mLocalPlayer.setAudioStreamType(mStreamType);
182            mLocalPlayer.prepare();
...
```

So, setURI creates a new MediaPlayer, then calls setDataSource on the MediaPlayer. The android doc tells us that using new MediaPlayer() sets it in "idle" state, and that "idle" state is the correct state for calling setDataSource.
I really do no understand how, apparently one time in a thousand, I get this error. I cannot contact the user who had the error, never reproduced it on my end, so I find myself blocked.
I'm thinking of catching the error in my code and when it happens, try again with my Ringtone.setStreamType, on the assumption that it happens because of a transient "state" of the system that may have changed a few milliseconds later. In short I am quite desperate :)

Any help or similar experiences would be appreciated :)

Comment: the error is from your side where the mediaplayer doesnt get the source of the proper format. Are you supporting all the format in your code.

Comment: what does destroyLocalPlayer();?
comment above may be right, check supported formats due to your OS version.http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
Try also to debug your URL, hardcode one and try with it

Comment: Thank you therealprashant and Hunkeone, I will try in this direction but it does not seem logical to me that a problem with the data source format leads to an IllegalStateException error and not, say, an IOException.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case, i had to call `reset()` on the `MediaPlayer` instance, before i supplied it with a different url.

As far as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) goes, setDataSource is only valid in IDLE state.

You can also visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816551/java-lang-illegalstateexception-what-does-it-mean) , explained very nicely using diagram.